# Reverse toggle commented and uncommented code at the same time

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> lets you comment selected lines if no line was previously commented or uncomment lines if each of them is commented /Toggle Comment/.

Is there a possibility to reverse comments?  So toggle off any commented lines and toggle on comments for any uncommented lines in a selected block of code?

Eg., now:

```
line 1    \                    // line 1
line 2       -> [Ctrl + /] ->  // line 2
// line 3 /                    // // line 3
```

Expected/desired:

```
line 1    \                      // line 1
line 2       -> [Ctrl + ???] ->  // line 2
// line 3 /                      line 3
```

Comment: Consider specifying tool/editor you are asking about...

Comment: Good point @AlexeiLevenkov. It's more about Visual Studio Code. I hoped that there is some universal standard like [Ctrl + C] / [Ctrl + V]. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Mark. Honestly, I think that your answer is very good from an engineer's point of view. At the same time, I feel ashamed for implementing such functionality in 2020 (write commands to have the possibility to write command...). It shouldn't be so complicated for rather routine actions. So, maybe someone does use it but I don't. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this pretty easily with one extra command:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> : which splits your selection into individual lines each with its own cursor.  Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> does exactly what you want.

You could make this into a macro, here using the macro extension [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command), to do this in one step:

In settings.json:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [
  {
    "command": "multiCommand.reverseComments",
    "sequence": [
      "editor.action.insertCursorAtEndOfEachLineSelected",
      "editor.action.commentLine",
      "removeSecondaryCursors"
    ]
  }
]
```

In your keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+/",             // or whatever keybinding you wish
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.reverseComments" },
  "when": "textInputFocus && editorHasSelection"
},
```

This looks pretty useful, I think I will use it too.  You will lose the original selection, which the default behaviour would retain, as the demo shows:

[image: toggle comments]

Comment: Thank you @Mark. It's a really good solution. Genius lies in simplicity ) I could only add that in this case eslint(prettier) should be corrected; because when the lines of code begin on the different levels, every line will be individually delimited by `//` - prettifier will not like that.

And just in case, how to edit `keybindings.json` is right [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings).

Comment: So get rid of prettier ;} This macro does what vscode would do otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I just uploaded an extension [Toggle Line Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.toggle-comments) that will do what you want.  So that

```
line 1
line 2
// line 3
```

would become

```
// line 1
// line 2
line 3
```

and vice-versa.

Demo:

[image: toggle line comments demo]

<kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> is the default keybinding but you can change that as the extension contributes one command:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+/",
  "command": "toggle-comments.toggleLineComments",
  "when": "editorHasSelection && editorTextFocus"
}
```

It'll work on multiple selections as well.